# Where to include common files in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to know where to include files that are used extensively in the code.e.g: a "functions.php" file that contains common functions used amongst all the controllers.Since it doesn't look right to include it in every controller, where should I put the "include" statement it?

Comment: Convert everything in functions.php (which presumably contains procedural code) to OO, and `use` the classes as normal

Comment: Converting functions to OO is not a right pattern.

Comment: @Talus what do you mean by 'not a right pattern'? Are you suggesting it's better to leave a load of functions arbitrarily dumped in an include file than to refactor said functions into a reusable OO library or Symfony service? I'm not sure how you would justify that opinion

Comment: A (set of) function(s), is what it means : a set of functions. It does not have any sense to have a pseudo object that group these. You wouldn't have a `MiscFunctions` object, would you ? What would be its purpose (except "regrouping my php functions", which is not really correct, as this couldn't be a true "object") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using composer, you can specify a directive that includes automatically some files : https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files